# Positioning an absolute element on a zooming image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some very simple code but I encountered an issue. I have a background image which is zoomed in upon scroll. I would like to relatively position an element relative to the background image which takes up the full width and height of the screen. How could I do this? I thought it would be as simple as having relative and absolute containers. For better context here is the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqfpr.jpg). I am attempting to place an element on the screen of the camera. Do I have to think of a more outside of the box approach? Thank you.

Here is some of the very simple code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(".hero-zoom img").css({
width: (100 + scroll/5)  + "%",
top: -(scroll/10)  + "%",
});
});
</script>

header img{
width: 100%;
max-width: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```